# Can we consider a circle as a function?

Tags: functions, analytic-geometry, graphing-functions

I heard that a circle is not a function mathematically speaking, because for some $x$, there are two corresponding $y$. I agree, but if the function takes a $x$ and a $y$, we have only one output per input. So is this:
$$
f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 - r^2
$$
a function, mathematically speaking?

Comment: Yes this is a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"a circle is not a function" is a clumsy way to say that a circle cannot be represented as the graph of a function $y=f(x)$, as a given abscissa may correspond to two distinct ordinates. Recall that a circle is a geometric entity, while a function is a relation between real numbers, so the two terms are not of the same nature.

From the *implicit equation*

$$x^2+y^2-r^2=0$$

we draw

$$y=\pm\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$$

and a circle can be represented as the union of the graphs of the two *functions* $f(x)=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ and $g(x)=-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$.

---

Now

$$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-r^2$$ is indeed a function of two arguments, and the *locus* of $f(x,y)=0$ is a circle.

You might also be interested in the 3D locus

$$z=f(x,y),$$

which corresponds to a paraboloid of revolution.

[image]

Any horizontal cross-section through the paraboloid is a circle.

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed a function, but not of a circle. It forms a paraboloid. The equation $f(x,y)=0$ does describe a circle.
 A function whose image is a circle would be something like $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2:t \mapsto g(t) = (\cos(t),\sin(t))$.

However, a circle is a geometrical object, while a function is not, so you can never really say that a function 'is' a circle.

Comment: While you can't say that the function of the circle, it would be fair to say that the range of $g$ is a circle, or that the graph of $y=2x$ is a straight line.